# is there a new equalivant of _malloca

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management

I am a big fan of the _malloca but I can't use it with classes.  Is there a stack based dynamic allocation method for classes.

Is this a bad idea, another vestige of c which should ideologically be opposed or just continue to use it for limited purposes.

Comment: Declaring a C++ object as a local variable is effectively the same thing, no ? Plus you get the automatic destructor call.

Comment: yes but thats at compile time not runtime.  I can't allocate a new pointer to a class on the stack at runtime.

Comment: Forcing stack allocation is evil.

Comment: @Nikolai:  Assuming rerun 'knows' that s/he won't blow through the entire stack, why is this evil?

Comment: Why do you want to allocate dynamically from the stack?  Are you allocating single objects?  If so, you're better off using a local variable from the stack, as Paul says, especially as you still can use it as a reference, or pass its address (if that's necessary).  Are you attempting to use polymorphism?  If so, why the stack?  Are you allocating multiple objects?  If so, why not use a vector?

Comment: @Liz:  Maybe this is in high-performance code and heap contention is an issue.  Plus no need for head coalescing on the free.  Who knows *why* rerun needs/wants to do this.  Can't we just assume there is a good reason?

Comment: @John: if he has to ask, he probably *doesn't know*. Besides, this is C++, so no destructors.

Comment: This is the core of our application and we were having performance issues with allocation and deallocation.  Our first step was to preallocate and use static buffers, but this was very error prone.  For smaller blocks we began to use stack allocation and it worked great.  I had to make a modification to this code today and realized I had never used these tools with classes (mostly because I never had too) and was unaware how if you needed to how it could be accomplished.  Hence the question.

Comment: What about a `unique_ptr` specialization with a custom deleter that calls `_freea()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use _malloca with classes by allocating the memory (with _malloca) then constructing the class using placement new.

```
void* stackMemory = _malloca(sizeof(MyClass));
if( stackMemory ) {
   MyClass* myClass = new(stackMemory) MyClass(args);
   myClass->~MyClass();
}
```

Whether you should do this is another matter...

Comment: Let's fill in the dots in this answer: this is pointless.  The compiler already generates code like this, it never forgets to call the destructor.  Even when the code throws an exception.

Comment: What if you want to choose which of several derived classes to instantiate without heap allocation? And of course you need to be careful with calling the destructor - using RAII would be a good idea. But as it currently stands, the code in the answer never fails to call the destructor, even when an exception is thrown.

Comment: @HansPassant: lol this is > 1 year later, but I thought I'd mention: this isn't *quite* pointless becomes sometimes you need your buffer to have a bigger size than the object.

Answer (score 5):

You should probably avoid _malloca where possible, because you can cause a stack overflow if you allocate too much memory - especially a problem if you're allocating a variable amount of memory.

Joe's code will work but note the destructor is never called automatically in the case an exception is thrown, or if the function returns early, etc. so it's still risky.  Best to only keep plain old data in any memory allocated by _malloca.

The best way to put C++ objects on the stack is the normal way :)

```
MyClass my_stack_class;
```